# Find file which name contains given substrings simultaneously

Tags: bash, find

In general, it's often needed to find a file whose name should contain several substrings simultaneously. How do I do that with bash?

For example, "boost", "qt" and "linux" in a file called "How to link boost with qt under linux.htm"

P.S Finally, I've managed to find the file using:

```
find . -name *boost* | xargs find . -name *Qt*
```

but first it gives out this complaint:

```
xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option
find: paths must precede expression
```

So, I'm still looking for some clearer solution.

P.S The solution of Stéphane Chazelas has helped. The issue was with big letter 'b' in "boost", so I should've made this find case-insensitive:

```
find . -iname '*boost*' -iname '*qt*'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find /some/path -name '*boost*' -name '*Qt*'
```

Or to match on the full path:

```
find /some/path -path '*boost*' -path '*Qt*'
```

If you don't quote those patterns, they'll be expanded by your shell first.

For case insensitive match, some `find` implementations have `-iname`/`-ipath`. Otherwise, you can always do:

```
find /some/path -name '*[bB][oO][oO][sS][tT]*' -name '*[qQ][tT]*'
```

Or, assuming file paths don't contain newline characters:

```
find /some/path |
  awk -F/ '{lname=tolower($NF)}; lname ~ /boost/ && lname ~ /qt/'
```

Comment: I've tried the both - they didn't give any output on my machine.

Comment: Sorry. It helped. The issue was boost was with 'b' letter: it was  "Boost".

Comment: So how to make "find" it case-insensitive in my case?

Answer (score 1):

Use `find /some/path -name "*boost*" -a -name "*qt*"` etc.

The `-a` means "and" to find.

Comment: I've already tried that. It didn't work for me. But the file exists.

Comment: Did it give an error? Did it not find the file(s)?

Comment: No, it didn't give an error message. I've updated the question, look P.S.

Comment: @alxprogger this will work, at least on GNU find. Note that you need to quote the strings as in the updated answer": `"*boost*"`, not `*boost*`. Your updated question doesn't show what happens when you try this.

Comment: Thanks, @terdon, for the edit and comment. @alxprogger, you don't need two `find` commands and the xargs (in your updated question) -- just the one find.

Comment: I put both boost and Qt in quotes, but it didn't give any output.

Comment: Thanks to everybody. It was my lack of attention. The problem is solved

Comment: Glad you found a solution. I see your update regarding "Boost" vs "boost"; if you're not sure about the case of the filename, you might consider a more generic "find" command (`find /some/path -type f` for example) followed by an `egrep -i "string1|string2|string3..."` to catch filenames in a case-insensitive manner.